# Using R to get all search results from webpage when it's JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, html, r, v8

I am new to web scraping and I'm trying to get search results from the following website using R:

https://devtracker.fcdo.gov.uk/sector/1/projects

It is easy getting the first page of results, e.g. using

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)
link <- 'https://devtracker.fcdo.gov.uk/sector/1/projects'

devtracker = read_html(link)        
searchresults = devtracker %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="search-result"]//a',) %>% html_attr('href')
```

but I haven't been able to get results from subsequent pages. Initially I thought I would find the link to the next page, and follow it, and get the search results page by page. Looking at the html code in the browser it looks the following line:

```
pages = devtracker %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class='six columns']//ul//li",)
```

should find the links to other pages, but this returns an empty node set. I know that this is something to do with the page using JavaScript for the list of pages, and I tried using V8 for this following this blog: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/11/scraping-javascript-rendered-web-content-using-r/ but couldn't figure out how to use it to show the next page of results.

Is there an easy way for a newbie to get all the search results from this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a much better alternative for you. A quick inspection of the HTTP requests shows that the HTML is being rendered from JSON data which you can access directly at:

```
https://devtracker.fcdo.gov.uk/api/activities/?hierarchy=1&page_size=200&format=json&reporting_organisation_identifier=GB-GOV-15,GB-GOV-9,GB-GOV-6,GB-GOV-2,GB-GOV-1,GB-1,GB-GOV-3,GB-GOV-13,GB-GOV-7,GB-GOV-50,GB-GOV-52,GB-6,GB-10,GB-GOV-10,GB-9,GB-GOV-8,GB-GOV-5,GB-GOV-12,GB-COH-RC000346,GB-COH-03877777&fields=activity_dates,aggregations,activity_status,id,iati_identifier,url,title,reporting_organisation,activity_plus_child_aggregation,descriptions&activity_status=2&ordering=-activity_plus_child_budget_value&total_hierarchy_budget_gte=&total_hierarchy_budget_lte=&actual_start_date_gte=&planned_end_date_lte=&sector=&related_activity_sector=11110,11120,11130,11182,11220,11230,11240,11320,11330,11420,11430,11231,11232,11321,11322,&recipient_country=&recipient_region=&document_link_category=&participating_organisation=&page=1&format=json
```

You can change the `page_size` and `page` parameters to get everything in possibly one request, then parse using `jsonlite` or similar package.